# SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in TwilioQuest

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey I'm trying to learn JavaScript right now with TwilioQuest and im having problems that I cant seem to fix.

I'm trying to correct the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier". I'm getting when I try to run this code.

```js
Function getLaserSetting(magicWord) {
    if (magicWord === 'please') {
       return 'OFF';
    } else {
       Return 'ON';
   }
}

const currentSetting = get LaserSetting('please');
console.log('The current laser setting is' + currentSetting);
```

the original code is:

```js
function getLaserSetting(magicWord) {
  if (magicWord === 'the magic word here') {
    return 'what should this be?';
  } else {
    return 'ON';
  }
}

const currentSetting = getLaserSetting('right now!');
console.log('The current laser setting is: ' + currentSetting);
```

Comment: Can I recommend that you compare the two pieces of code you've provided? I think with even a small amount of effort you could spot the difference. That alone should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Function` must be written from small letter, `Return` must start from lowercase, name of variable `get LaserSetting`  must be without spaces.

So, Function -> function, Return -> return, get LaserSetting -> getLaserSetting.